# Sending HTTP/GET request from Google App Engine never makes it to its destination?

Tags: python, flask, google-app-engine, gunicorn, google-app-engine-python

I have a Python Flask application deployed on Google App Engine. One Flask view makes a request to another Flask view from Google App Engine, but the second request 'hangs' causing a ten-minute timeout with none of the code contained within the second Flask view to execute and does not produce an error.

It's quite large so here's a simplified version:

```
import flask
import urllib3

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/route-requests', methods=['GET'])
def route_requests_view():
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    resp = http.request('GET', url)    # where `url` is a separate service
    return ''

@app.route('/endpoint', methods=['GET'])
def endpoint_view():
    # Extract data from external data source ...
    # Add data to Firebase database ...
    return ''
```

The application accesses a `route-requests` view, where it starts a request to an `endpoint` view which then extracts data and adds it into a database (Firebase).

This works the majority of times. However, occasionally it will return these logs:

```
E 2022-01-13T07:45:00.391771Z GET 500 0 B 604.6 s AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) /route-requests-for-data-extraction GET 500 0 B 604.6 s AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) 61dfd87c00ff05f9dbc6f0d06e0001667e6e6176696761746f722d3333373432330001323032323031313374313634313539000100
A 2022-01-13T07:45:00.395674Z [2022-01-13 07:45:00 +0000] [19] [DEBUG] GET /route-requests-for-data-extraction 
A 2022-01-13T07:45:00.396123Z [2022-01-13 07:45:00 +0000] [19] [INFO] Starting to route request... 
A 2022-01-13T07:45:00.396641Z [2022-01-13 07:45:00 +0000] [19] [INFO] Sending request to API endpoint... 
E 2022-01-13T07:45:00.593732Z GET 500 0 B 604.4 s python-urllib3/1.26.8 /data-extraction-endpoint GET 500 0 B 604.4 s python-urllib3/1.26.8 61dfd87c00ff0901d50115b9c90001667e6e6176696761746f722d3333373432330001323032323031313374313634313539000100
A 2022-01-13T07:45:19.667346Z [2022-01-13 07:45:19 +0000] [10] [INFO] Handling signal: term 
A 2022-01-13T07:45:19.668474Z [2022-01-13 07:45:19 +0000] [19] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 19) 
A 2022-01-13T07:45:19.970713Z [2022-01-13 07:45:19 +0000] [10] [INFO] Shutting down: Master 
A 2022-01-13T07:45:19.971558Z Waiting up to 5 seconds. 
A 2022-01-13T07:45:19.971932Z Sent all pending logs. 
A 2022-01-13T07:45:19.972094Z Waiting up to 5 seconds. 
A 2022-01-13T07:45:19.972280Z Sent all pending logs. 
A 2022-01-13T07:45:19.972355Z Waiting up to 5 seconds. 
A 2022-01-13T07:45:19.972525Z Sent all pending logs. 
A 2022-01-13T07:55:01.965038Z [2022-01-13 07:55:01 +0000] [10] [INFO] Handling signal: term
```

Now, from the logs, the first request to the `route-requests` view is successful and is able to make the second request to the `endpoint` view. However, logging messages contained within the `endpoint` view is never logged which suggests, despite an attempted request, it never makes it to the endpoint.

There seems to be no error within the code other than a 500 error caused by a 10-minute timeout from Google App Engine.

My guess is the problem stems from the point the second request is sent since using `urllib3` and `requests` manually to access the `endpoint` view directly can reproduce the 'request stall', without having to go through the `route-requests` view first.

Here is the `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: python39
instance_class: F2
service: default
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 1 main:app --preload --timeout 0 --log-level=DEBUG
```

Not sure if this information is useful but there are no idle instances when the requests are made, so Google App Engine have to initiate new instances (two instances) upon the requests.

And here is a typical successful request to both Flask views from Google App Engine:

```
A 2022-01-13T07:30:00.505461Z GET 200 172 B 17.9 s AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) /route-requests-for-data-extraction GET 200 172 B 17.9 s AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) 61dfd4f800ff07b614fd45a4380001667e6e6176696761746f722d3333373432330001323032323031313374313634313539000100
A 2022-01-13T07:30:00.509619Z [2022-01-13 07:30:00 +0000] [19] [DEBUG] GET /route-requests-for-data-extraction 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:00.510122Z [2022-01-13 07:30:00 +0000] [19] [INFO] Starting to route request... 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:00.510707Z [2022-01-13 07:30:00 +0000] [19] [INFO] Sending request to API endpoint... 
I 2022-01-13T07:30:00.710063Z GET 200 172 B 17.7 s python-urllib3/1.26.8 /data-extraction-endpoint GET 200 172 B 17.7 s python-urllib3/1.26.8 61dfd4f800ff0ac63fb8d7c6e20001667e6e6176696761746f722d33333734323300017365727669636574776f3a323032323031313374313634313539000100
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609454Z [2022-01-13 07:30:01 +0000] [10] [DEBUG] Current configuration: 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609487Z   config: ./gunicorn.conf.py 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609496Z   wsgi_app: None 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609502Z   bind: [':8081'] 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609511Z   backlog: 2048 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609517Z   workers: 1 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609523Z   worker_class: sync 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609528Z   threads: 1 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609545Z   worker_connections: 1000 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609552Z   max_requests: 0 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609557Z   max_requests_jitter: 0 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609562Z   timeout: 0 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609568Z   graceful_timeout: 30 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609573Z   keepalive: 2 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609579Z   limit_request_line: 4094 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609584Z   limit_request_fields: 100 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609590Z   limit_request_field_size: 8190 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609595Z   reload: False 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609600Z   reload_engine: auto 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609606Z   reload_extra_files: [] 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609611Z   spew: False 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609616Z   check_config: False 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609621Z   print_config: False 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609626Z   preload_app: True 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609632Z   sendfile: None 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609637Z   reuse_port: False 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609644Z   chdir: /workspace 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609648Z   daemon: False 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609653Z   raw_env: [] 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609659Z   pidfile: None 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609664Z   worker_tmp_dir: None 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609670Z   user: 33 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609674Z   group: 33 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609679Z   umask: 0 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609684Z   initgroups: False 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609689Z   tmp_upload_dir: None 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609697Z   secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'} 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609702Z   forwarded_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1'] 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609707Z   accesslog: None 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609712Z   disable_redirect_access_to_syslog: False 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609717Z   access_log_format: %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s" 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609722Z   errorlog: - 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609726Z   loglevel: DEBUG 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609731Z   capture_output: False 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609736Z   logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609742Z   logconfig: None 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609746Z   logconfig_dict: {} 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609751Z   syslog_addr: udp://localhost:514 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609756Z   syslog: False 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609761Z   syslog_prefix: None 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609765Z   syslog_facility: user 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609770Z   enable_stdio_inheritance: False 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609775Z   statsd_host: None 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609779Z   dogstatsd_tags:  
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609783Z   statsd_prefix:  
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609789Z   proc_name: None 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609794Z   default_proc_name: navigator.main:app 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609799Z   pythonpath: None 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609804Z   paste: None 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609808Z   on_starting: <function OnStarting.on_starting at 0x3e32c5d88a60> 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609813Z   on_reload: <function OnReload.on_reload at 0x3e32c5d88b80> 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609819Z   when_ready: <function WhenReady.when_ready at 0x3e32c5d88ca0> 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609824Z   pre_fork: <function Prefork.pre_fork at 0x3e32c5d88dc0> 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609830Z   post_fork: <function Postfork.post_fork at 0x3e32c5d88ee0> 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609834Z   post_worker_init: <function PostWorkerInit.post_worker_init at 0x3e32c5da2040> 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609839Z   worker_int: <function WorkerInt.worker_int at 0x3e32c5da2160> 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609845Z   worker_abort: <function WorkerAbort.worker_abort at 0x3e32c5da2280> 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609850Z   pre_exec: <function PreExec.pre_exec at 0x3e32c5da23a0> 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609855Z   pre_request: <function PreRequest.pre_request at 0x3e32c5da24c0> 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609861Z   post_request: <function PostRequest.post_request at 0x3e32c5da2550> 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609866Z   child_exit: <function ChildExit.child_exit at 0x3e32c5da2670> 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609871Z   worker_exit: <function WorkerExit.worker_exit at 0x3e32c5da2790> 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609875Z   nworkers_changed: <function NumWorkersChanged.nworkers_changed at 0x3e32c5da28b0> 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609881Z   on_exit: <function OnExit.on_exit at 0x3e32c5da29d0> 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609886Z   proxy_protocol: False 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609891Z   proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1'] 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609897Z   keyfile: None 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609902Z   certfile: None 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609906Z   ssl_version: 2 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609911Z   cert_reqs: 0 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609915Z   ca_certs: None 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609920Z   suppress_ragged_eofs: True 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609925Z   do_handshake_on_connect: False 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609930Z   ciphers: None 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609934Z   raw_paste_global_conf: [] 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:01.609939Z   strip_header_spaces: False 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:03.483444Z [2022-01-13 07:30:03 +0000] [10] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:03.484514Z [2022-01-13 07:30:03 +0000] [10] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:03.484561Z [2022-01-13 07:30:03 +0000] [10] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (10) 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:03.484637Z [2022-01-13 07:30:03 +0000] [10] [INFO] Using worker: sync 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:03.570605Z [2022-01-13 07:30:03 +0000] [19] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:03.592609Z [2022-01-13 07:30:03 +0000] [19] [DEBUG] Closing connection.  
A 2022-01-13T07:30:03.595681Z [2022-01-13 07:30:03 +0000] [19] [DEBUG] GET /data-extraction-endpoint 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:03.600922Z [2022-01-13 07:30:03 +0000] [19] [INFO] Starting map voyage... 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:03.608726Z [2022-01-13 07:30:03 +0000] [19] [INFO] Opening browser... 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:03.610593Z [2022-01-13 07:30:03 +0000] [10] [DEBUG] 1 workers 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:05.855181Z [2022-01-13 07:30:05 +0000] [19] [INFO] Browser opened! 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:05.855474Z [2022-01-13 07:30:05 +0000] [19] [INFO] Opening page... 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:05.952343Z [2022-01-13 07:30:05 +0000] [19] [INFO] Page opened! 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:05.953879Z [2022-01-13 07:30:05 +0000] [19] [INFO] Starting request to external data source... 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:07.015722Z [2022-01-13 07:30:07 +0000] [19] [INFO] Request to external data source completed! 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:07.016011Z [2022-01-13 07:30:07 +0000] [19] [INFO] Starting data extraction... 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:15.329382Z [2022-01-13 07:30:15 +0000] [10] [INFO] Handling signal: term 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:15.330523Z [2022-01-13 07:30:15 +0000] [19] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 19) 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:15.669468Z [2022-01-13 07:30:15 +0000] [10] [INFO] Shutting down: Master 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:15.670194Z Waiting up to 5 seconds. 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:15.670520Z Sent all pending logs. 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:15.670775Z Waiting up to 5 seconds. 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:15.670946Z Sent all pending logs. 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:15.671059Z Waiting up to 5 seconds. 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:15.671236Z Sent all pending logs. 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:17.821551Z [2022-01-13 07:30:17 +0000] [19] [INFO] Data extraction completed! 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:17.821795Z [2022-01-13 07:30:17 +0000] [19] [INFO] Closing page... 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:17.827775Z [2022-01-13 07:30:17 +0000] [19] [INFO] Page closed! 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:17.828005Z [2022-01-13 07:30:17 +0000] [19] [INFO] Closing browser... 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:17.847428Z [2022-01-13 07:30:17 +0000] [19] [INFO] Browser closed! 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:18.061252Z [2022-01-13 07:30:18 +0000] [19] [INFO] Map voyage completed! 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:18.064588Z [2022-01-13 07:30:18 +0000] [19] [INFO] Adding data into database... 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:18.370364Z [2022-01-13 07:30:18 +0000] [19] [INFO] Data added into database! 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:18.386824Z [2022-01-13 07:30:18 +0000] [19] [INFO] Request to API endpoint completed! 
A 2022-01-13T07:30:18.387348Z [2022-01-13 07:30:18 +0000] [19] [INFO] Request to route request completed!
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The log for the bit that doesn't work shows your request to the data-extraction endpoint returns a status of 500. So I think it hits the view. Seeing/not seeing the logging messages will depend on where you put them. Try putting a message on the first line of the code to at least confirm the view is accessed. If that appears, then it seems your issue is with the bit that is extracting data from an external source. Either the issue is your own code or the 3rd party provider

Comment: @NoCommandLine I added a message on the first line of code so I'll see how it goes as the request hang strangely only happens sometimes.